# How to set the style for a word without changing the entire style of the paragraph?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-style

I am trying to make a macro which changes the style of all words in the document one by one, depending on the their current style, as in the actual style name and the font size and name.

My problem is that, when I change the style of the very first word, it then changes the style of entire paragraph, which is very much not intended.

```
'Loop trough all words
For Each w In p.Range.Words
...

...

'Switch based on the style of the word
Select Case r
    Case "b"
        w.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyleB")
      ...
```

The property .CharacterStyle is readonly, however when I use the code below, only the word gets the style applied, as it should, it does however not keep the style in its style property or its character style property, which is quite important, so I am at a loss about what to do.

```
'Loop trough all words
For Each w In p.Range.Words
...

...

'Switch based on the style of the word
Select Case r
    Case "b"
        w.CharacterStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("NewStyleB")
      ...
```

Comment: *NewStyleB* needs to be a character style (or a linked style). Then you can set the `Style` property of the `Word` object: `w.Style = "NewStyleB"`

Answer (score 0):

Word has few [style types](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Style-basics-in-Word-d382f84d-5c38-4444-98a5-9cbb6ede1ba4#bm2). Check if your style is a paragraph style, and if it is then you can copy it to a new style and change it to a character style.